# Elegant way to walk backward through OneToOne table entities with Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a very simply structured entity that contains a simple association

**Database_Entity_Tenant**

```
id         (primary key)
parentId   (id of the parent entry)
code       (a simple identifier for the tenant, unique)
```

I defined parentId in my entity accordingly:

```
/**  
 * @Column(type="integer")
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Tenant")
 * @JoinColumn(name="parentTenantId", referencedColumnName="id")
 * **/
 protected $parentId;
```

This works fine - the generated database schema resembles my choices and its good.

Now i am writing my first method which basically has to return an array of all the tenants that are chained together, in reverse order (i use this for walking backward through a chain of tenants).

In order to do that i came up with the idea to use a while() loop.

```
$currentTenant = {DATABASE_ENTITY_TENANT}; // In my real code i fetch the entity object of the current tenant

$chain[] = $currentTenant; 

$repository = Database::entityManager()->getRepository('Database_Entity_Tenant');

while(!$currentTenant->getParentId()){
    $currentTenant = $repository->findOneBy(array(
        'id' => $currentTenant->getParentId()
    ));
    $chain[] = $currentTenant;
}
```

Any tenant that has no parent (such as the base tenant) will have no parent id (or null), so that would end the while loop.

Now all this may work, but it seems really rough to me. I am fairly new to Doctrine so i don't know much about it but i am sure there is some way to do this more elegantly.

**QUESTION**

Does Doctrine 2 provide me with any set of functions i could use to solve the above problem in a better way?

If not, then is there any other way to do this more elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not getting your problem wrong, you just need to find all the entries in your association table ordered by the `parentId`. In Doctrine2 you can do the following:

```
$currentTenant = {DATABASE_ENTITY_TENANT}; // assuming a valid entity

$repository = Database::entityManager()
    ->getRepository('Database_Entity_Tenant')
    ->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->where('t.parentId IS NOT NULL')
    ->andWhere('t.parentId < :current') /* < or > */
    ->setParameter('current', $currentTenant->getParentId()->getId())
    ->orderBy('t.parentId', 'ASC') /* ASC or DESC, no array_reverse */
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();

/* At this point $repository contains all what you need because of Doctrine,
 * but if you want a chain variable: */

$chain = array();
foreach ($repository as $tenant) {
    $chain[] = $tenant->getCode(); // your tenant entity if your entity is mapped correctly
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That looks very good. Thank You. I will try to implement it and see how it goes. However, i was wondering: is there no prepared functionality so that i could implement something like {Database_Entity_Tenant}->getParent() ? Would that not be the more object-oriented approach?

Comment: Upon implementing it, i fail to see where this code takes care of the relation. Its like this: when i call it, i use the currently set tenant as the starting point. Then i walk backwards from there on. Therefore i don't think the above code can really pose a solution for my problem.

Comment: My code will work if you have both `Database_Entity_Tenant` and `Tenant` entities mapped correctly. With correctly I mean: `code` should be a foreign key for the primary key of the`Tenan` entity, a 1:1 relation. But as I told you, I don't know if I'm getting it wrong... Try it and let me  know.

Comment: Thanks. The mapping should be correct. I tried it but have to add more test data to see if it performs correctly. In the meantime i have extended my code - i am now using a custom repository and this is where i will put the method to retrieve the parent chain.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work as intended. The problem is that nowhere in this code there is a starting point (and i don't know where and how to implement it). Imagine ID:5 has a parent ID:4 and ID:4 has a parent ID:3 - my intention is to get the chain STARTING from a specific point (for instance from ID:4).

Comment: If you have `$currentTenant = {DATABASE_ENTITY_TENANT};` you can add a `where` clause to the query. I'll modify my answer

Comment: Done, set the direction by using > or <

Comment: I am implementing it. What i do not understand is why you use orderBy - isn't the order supposed to be bound to the logical inheritance order of the entries in the table?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Unfortunately. Also, how is < or > a direction? The parent ids do not have any such order. ID 200 could be a parent of ID 500 for instance.